# error loading all element with Beautifulsoup in dynamic load page without load more button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the elements from the page [https://www.doce34.cl/g-shock?order=OrderByNameASC&page="](https://www.doce34.cl/g-shock?order=OrderByNameASC&page=%22) , the issue is that the script only gets 8 and there are 24 per page. I've tried several ways but i have not succeeded. can someone help me? thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

headers = {
   "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36",
}
filename1 = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
hora=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
print (hora)

url = "https://www.doce34.cl/g-shock?order=OrderByNameASC&page="
download_delay = 3
for page in range(1,40):
    req = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = bs(req.text,'html.parser')
    contenedor_de_productos = soup.find(class_="vtex-search-result-3-x-gallery flex flex-row flex-wrap items-stretch bn ph1 na4 pl9-l")
    lista_de_productos = soup.find_all('div', class_='vtex-search-result-3-x-galleryItem vtex-search-result-3-x-galleryItem--normal pa4')
    contador_producto=1
    for producto in  lista_de_productos:
        print("producto numero " + str(contador_producto))
        texto_producto=producto.find(class_="vtex-product-summary-2-x-productNameContainer mv0 vtex-product-summary-2-x-nameWrapper overflow-hidden c-on-base f5").text
        texto_producto=texto_producto.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace(',', '').replace('"', '').strip()

        texto_producto_link = producto.find(class_="vtex-product-summary-2-x-container vtex-product-summary-2-x-container--product-summary vtex-product-summary-2-x-containerNormal vtex-product-summary-2-x-containerNormal--product-summary overflow-hidden br3 h-100 w-100 flex flex-column justify-between center tc").a['href']
        texto_producto_precio = producto.find(class_="vtex-product-price-1-x-currencyInteger").text

        contador_producto = contador_producto + 1
        print(texto_producto)
```

Comment: there are a lot more that 24 in a page

Comment: you get only 8 per page because the HTML content only contains 8 of those target classes "vtex-search-result-3-x-galleryItem vtex-search-result-3-x-galleryItem--normal pa4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments,

```
lista_de_productos = soup.find_all('div', class_='vtex-search-result-3-x-galleryItem vtex-search-result-3-x-galleryItem--normal pa4')
print(len(lista_de_productos))
>> 8
```

you get only 8 products per page because the HTML content only contains 8 of these target classes which hold the individual product details.

You're right every page consists of 24 products, however, only 8 of these are available under the div elements.

But the good news is that all 24 product details are stored as JSON data in the script tag.

Here is the complete solution:

```
import json
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
   "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36",
}
filename1 = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
hora = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
print(hora)

url = "https://www.doce34.cl/g-shock?order=OrderByNameASC&page="
contador_producto=1

# a list that will contain all individual products from all the pages
all_product = []

for page in range(1, 5):
    req = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')

    json_script_tags = soup.find_all('script', attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"})[-1]
    print(len(json_script_tags))
    lista_de_productos = json.loads(json_script_tags.text)

    print(f"Number of products on page {page}: {len(lista_de_productos['itemListElement'])}")

    for producto in lista_de_productos['itemListElement']:
        print("producto numero " + str(contador_producto))
        product_dict = {
            "product_name": producto['item']['name'],
            "product_brand": producto['item']['brand']['name'],
            "product_image": producto['item']['image'],
            "product_description": producto['item']['description'],
            "product_link": producto['item']['@id'],
            "product_price": producto['item']['offers']['lowPrice']
           }

        # a dictionary containing individual product information
        print(product_dict)
        all_product.append(product_dict)
        contador_producto += 1
    time.sleep(1)

print(all_product)
# check the length of all_product. For example, it will be 96(24*4) for 4 pages.
# print(len(all_product))
```

I hope it's helpful.